# C# and EF Can not connect to remote MySql Server but MySql workbench connects

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I have this Mysql database on a remote hosting provider. I have MySql workbench installed and with the following information:

```
server,
username,
pw
```

it connects ok but when i try with visualstudio i get this error  [image]

i am using MySql connector from MySql's website. Also when trying to connect with the following connection string in EntityFramework

```
Server=tango.rdb.superhosting.bg;Database=ulprojec_weatheronmars;Uid=ulpro_georgi_it;Pwd=password;
```

i get the following error

```
An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
```

And still through MySql workbench i can execute LINQ and etc.

Comment: Dude, if your screen shot is correct, the problem is because you are using the Microsoft SQL Server driver to connect to MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you Visual Studio screenshot, you are trying to connect with the Sql Server driver. You should be using the MySql driver. My guess is that you are doing the same with Entity Framework.

Disclaimer: I haven't used MySql with either, so I wouldn't know where to get the drivers. I'm sure Google would know.

Comment: damn i am stupid, i just ignored that on the bottom line is MySql Database provider althogth i installed it. I gotta get some sleep ;d, thank you anyways.

Comment: @georgi-it - if this solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.